# Convert binary string to integer in php

Tags: php, string, binary, integer, typeconverter

In php how do I convert a string "1010101010" into the integer value represented by this binary number?

eg "10" would go to 2, "101" would go to 5

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`bindec()`](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/function.bindec.php) function to convert from binary to decimal:

```
$value = bindec("10101011010101");
```

Comment: I knew there had to be a function for it somewhere

Answer (score 2):

Try the [`bindec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bindec.php) function.

Comment: how to convert integer greater than limits